# GlobalSign cert in Trusted root for Google Services shows Sha1. Security postures

Tags: keys, sha-1, certificates

"GlobalSign" certificate in Trusted Root Certification Authorities for Google Services shows Sha1.  Security postures are different than just 2-3 yr ago.  At my home, router bought 2016, networked; and no use of RSA hard fob as I did; (cert has dates 2006-2021). May I best remove it to tame my internal concerns from online events raising questions about information assurance  (e.g. use MMC console on Windows 10 at home)?

Comment: The signature on a root cert, including its hash, has zero effect on security; there are several existing Qs on this. https://pki.goog/ shows GlobalSign (GS) R2 with SHA1 fingerprint beginning 75:e0:ab:b6 still valid (although that site itself depends on Google IA3 and GS R2, producing infinite recursion). Whether you want to remove it is up to you, although Windows since about 7 (including 10) will automatically when needed add roots to your machine's local store from Microsoft's root-program repository. (There are Qs on that also.)